# problem with reading partitioned parquet files created by Snowflake with pandas or arrow

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet, pyarrow, duckdb

```
ArrowInvalid: Unable to merge: Field X has incompatible types: string vs dictionary<values=string, indices=int32, ordered=0>

ArrowInvalid: Unable to merge: Field X has incompatible types: decimal vs int32
```

I am trying to write the result of a snowflake query on disk and then query that data using arrow and duckdb. I have created a partitioned parquet with the query bellow following [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#syntax):

```
COPY INTO 's3://path/to/folder/'
FROM (
    SELECT transaction.TRANSACTION_ID, OUTPUT_SCORE, MODEL_NAME, ACCOUNT_ID, to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE,'YYYY-MM') as SCORE_MTH
    FROM transaction
    )
partition by('SCORE_MTH=' || score_mth || '/ACCOUNT_ID=' || ACCOUNT_ID)
file_format = (type=parquet)
header=true
```

When I try to read the parquet files I get the following error:

```
df = pd.read_parquet('path/to/parquet/') # same result using pq.ParquetDataset or pq.read_table as they all use the same function under the hood

ArrowInvalid: Unable to merge: Field SCORE_MTH has incompatible types: string vs dictionary<values=string, indices=int32, ordered=0>
```

Moreover, following some google search I found this [page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13578?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17396598#comment-17396598). Following the instructions:
df = pd.read_parquet('path/to/parquet/', use_legacy_dataset=True)

```
ValueError: Schema in partition[SCORE_MTH=0, ACCOUNT_ID=0] /path/to/parquet was different. 
TRANSACTION_ID: string not null
OUTPUT_SCORE: double
MODEL_NAME: string
ACCOUNT_ID: int32
SCORE_MTH: string

vs

TRANSACTION_ID: string not null
OUTPUT_SCORE: double
MODEL_NAME: string
```

Also based on what the data type is you may get this error:

```
ArrowInvalid: Unable to merge: Field X has incompatible types: IntegerType vs DoubleType
```

or

```
ArrowInvalid: Unable to merge: Field X has incompatible types: decimal vs int32
```

This is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13851).

Any idea how I can read this parquet file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only work around I found that works is this:

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
dataset = ds.dataset('/path/to/parquet/', format="parquet", partitioning="hive")
```

then you can query directly using `duckdb`:

```
import duckdb
con = duckdb.connect()
pandas_df = con.execute("Select * from dataset").df()
```

Also if you want a pandas dataframe you can do this:

```
dataset.to_table().to_pandas()
```

Note that `to_table()` will load the whole dataset into memory.